# Combining two queries and getting the sum of count

Tags: mysql

I have two different queries that each do half the job I need. how to combine them.

orders table has `orderNumber` and `customerNumber`, **customers** table has `customerNumber` and `salesRepEmployeeNumber`, **orderdetails** has multiple lines of the same `orderNumber` each showing price&quantity of different items).

(counting the number of orders from different customers each sales rep has)

```sql
select c.salesRepEmployeeNumber, count(*)
from customers c
inner join orders o1
on c.customerNumber = o1.customerNumber
group by c.salesRepEmployeeNumber;
```

and

(counting the revenue made by each sales rep)

```sql
select c.salesRepEmployeeNumber, sum(o2.priceEach*o2.quantityOrdered) as "Revenue"
from customers c
inner join orders o1
on c.customerNumber = o1.customerNumber
inner join orderdetails o2
on o1.orderNumber = o2.orderNumber
group by c.salesRepEmployeeNumber;
```

I need a query to know the employee number, # of orders, and revenue. I tried

```sql
select sum(o2.priceEach*o2.quantityOrdered) as "Revenue", c.salesRepEmployeeNumber, count(*)
from customers c
inner join orders o1
on c.customerNumber = o1.customerNumber
inner join orderdetails o2
on o1.orderNumber = o2.orderNumber
group by c.salesRepEmployeeNumber;
```

but it returns the count of items/products from the orders (e.g. 1 order has three products)

Comment: Read about [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT salesRepEmployeeNumber,
       t1.`count(*)` AS `count`,
       t2.Revenue
FROM (complete text of 1st query) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (complete text of 2nd query) AS t2 USING (salesRepEmployeeNumber)
```

*complete text* means "without final semicolon".

If your data guarantees that the amount of rows produced by 2nd query is equal to one produced by 1st query then you may use not LEFT but INNER joining.

---

Also test

```sql
select c.salesRepEmployeeNumber
     , COUNT(DISTINCT o1.id) AS orders_count
     , sum(o2.priceEach*o2.quantityOrdered) as "Revenue"
  from customers c
  join orders o1
    on c.customerNumber = o1.customerNumber
  join orderdetails o2
    on o1.orderNumber = o2.orderNumber
 group 
    by c.salesRepEmployeeNumber;
```

where `o1.id` is primary key expression (or any unique non-NULL column/expression/index) of `orders` table.